# How to set a DataContext of multiple Views to one instance of ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism-6

I'm using a ViewModelLocator for my Views, it is configured in Bootstrapper with following method:

```
protected override void ConfigureViewModelLocator()
{
    base.ConfigureViewModelLocator();

    ViewModelLocationProvider.Register<ViewA, ViewABViewModel>();
    ViewModelLocationProvider.Register<ViewB, ViewABViewModel>();
}
```

It works fine, but makes two separate instances of a ViewModel for my 2 Views. 
I want my both Views to use the same instance of a ViewModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the [source code](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Prism/Mvvm/ViewModelLocationProvider.cs) shows the problem of creating a new instance for every view by default:

```
static Func<Type, object> _defaultViewModelFactory = type => Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Prism allows to define this method generally for all types or only special types. Second case should be preferred.

```
ViewModelLocationProvider.Register<ViewA, ViewABViewModel>();
```

only links the types of View and ViewModel together, no factory is defined. This means a new instance is created for each View. To use an instance at multiple views you need to define the factory method. Create one instance of your ViewModel

```
ViewABViewModel vm = new ViewABViewModel();
```

and register the factory methods for your Views by returning this already prepared instance

```
ViewModelLocationProvider.Register<ViewA>(() => vm);
ViewModelLocationProvider.Register<ViewB>(() => vm);
```

Prism is now taking this instance instead of creating a new one.

Answer (score 1):

You could register the view model as a singleton:

```
protected override void ConfigureViewModelLocator()
{
    base.ConfigureViewModelLocator();

    Container.RegisterType<ViewAViewModel>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager()); //<--
    ViewModelLocationProvider.Register<ViewA, ViewABViewModel>();
    ViewModelLocationProvider.Register<ViewB, ViewABViewModel>();
}
```

Or use the method overload that accepts a factory as suggested by @Fruchtzwerg.